# Haskell List Generation

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I found an interesting exercise and tried to solve it.

It requires that, given a number, its digits should be put in a list in reverse order.

Now, I almost managed to do it:

```
lastDigit :: Integer -> Integer
lastDigit x = x `mod` 10

dropLastDigit :: Integer -> Integer
dropLastDigit x = (x - lastDigit x) `div` 10

numba2listInReverse :: Integer -> [Integer]
numba2listInReverse x = lastDigit x : numba2listInReverse (dropLastDigit x)
```

The first function simply returns the last digit. The second returns the number deprived of its last digit. Finally, the last function generates the list. My problem is I cannot find a way to *stop* the recursion. Look at the output:

```
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> dropLastDigit 123
12
*Main> numba2listInReverse 12345
[5,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0Interrupted.
*Main>
```

It continues to put zeroes in the list even once the number is exhausted. How to solve this?

Comment: Test for `0` to end the recursion. Something like `numba2listInReverse 0 = []` (haven't tested it, but it's the basic idea)

Comment: A different way to solve this problem would be to use `reverse $ show x`.

Comment: I have to mention that there is a quick one-liner involving show and reverse that solves this problem.  Also, note that your output is correct, if you recognize that 1234 can also be written as ..00001234.

Comment: `dropLastDigit` could be written as `dropLastDigit = flip div 10`, you don't need the substraction.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, mates. Now, in order: 1) I didn't know neither "show" nor "reverse". But I'll investigate, it sound interesting, thanks! The same stands for "flip". 2) What if I have a number like 0000123 and want to put ALL of it in the list? Checking for zero would exclude the initial zero(es).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It continues to put zeroes in the list even once the number is exhausted.

That's because you did not tell Haskell to stop when the number is exhausted.

You define a *recursive* function. In order to write good (read *terminating*) recursive functions, you need a **stop condition**: a condition for which you stop calling the recursion.

You can do this by using a [*guard*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards):

```
numba2listInReverse :: Integer -> [Integer]
numba2listInReverse x | x == 0 = []
                      | otherwise = lastDigit x : numba2listInReverse (dropLastDigit x)
```

The guards are denoted with pipe characters (`|`) and are followed by conditions (like `x == 0` and `otherwise`). After the condition, the "assignment" operator is written followed by the expression to be evaluated if the condition holds. The conditions are tested in the *order you have written them*. In case of overlap, the first condition that succeeds will thus be "fired" (so to speak). `otherwise` is equal to `True` (you can test this for instance is `ghci`) and thus will always be fired if none of the above guards fired.

If zero (`0`) is thus given to the `numba2listInReverse` function, it will return the empty list (and no more recursion is done). Otherwise (`otherwise`) it will perform the recursion you've defined: "emit" the last digit as first symbol from the list, followed by the recursive step.

> **Note**: strictly speaking, in Haskell recursive functions do not necessarily need a *stop condition*: because of lazy evaluation, some recursive functions can exists that have no stop condition, for instance to define a list containing "*all*" prime numbers.

---

**EDIT**: In case you want to map `0` onto `[0]`, you **cannot** simply modify the above code to:

```
numba2listInReverse :: Integer -> [Integer]
numba2listInReverse x | x == 0 = [0]
                      | otherwise = lastDigit x : numba2listInReverse (dropLastDigit x)
```

Indeed, this would result in `42` being mapped on `[2,4,0]`. Now you can solve the problem by introducing a helper function, that will for instance handle the recursive case:

```
numba2listInReverse :: Integer -> [Integer]
numba2listInReverse x | x == 0 = [0]
                      | otherwise = help x
    where help x | x == 0 = []
                 | otherwise = lastDigit x : help (dropLastDigit x)
```

Here you thus leave the non-zero case to the `help` function.

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive reply. While I'm a haskell newcomer, I was however aware of guards and, believe it or not, I imagined exactly your solution. But I dropped it since I thought it would have stopped if at least one of the digits would have been zero.
Now, I understand my mistake, but a problem still stands: if the number **begins** with a zero, that zero will not be put in the list. May you suggest a workaround?

Comment: @MadHatter: see updated answer in case you want to map `0` onto `[0]`. What do you mean with *begins*, Haskell interprets `042` as `42`, you cannot know how the user has written a number.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Very well, understood..!